# name of commit in the terminal is different in the github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I try to combine commit for my branch. However, the id(?) or the name of the commit listed in the git hub is different with the terminal. How to resolve this problem so that i combine 3 commit into 1.

in the terminal the name of the commits are:

1. chapter_3
2. message content
3. chapter 7

in the github, the name of the commits are:

1. message content
2. chapter 7
3. merge branch 'main' into chapter_7

[commit listed in the github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieAR4.png)

Comment: Looks like you haven't pushed "chapter_3" to github.

Comment: rebase ur `chapter_3` commit to ur branch.